# Send XML request and get response back

Tags: xml, request, response

I have been struggling with this easy question for quite some time.

I am trying to post an XML request to this website but I don't even know where to start. Which software should be used in the first place?

The XML frame is described in the doc (http://profiles.catalyst.harvard.edu/docs/ProfilesRNS_DisambiguationEngine.pdf)

My question is more around WHERE to type it?

Thanks

Romain

Answer (score 0):

this is what is known as an RPC-XML request. you will be making web requests formatted in the way specified by the documentation. how you proceed depends on what language you'll be using. in C#, you'd do something like this:

```
// create a web request that'll post some xml content to a web service
string url = "http://profiles.catalyst.harvard.edu/services/GetPMIDs/default.asp";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";

// set the content length based on the data you are passing through the
// web call
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<generated xml here as a string>");
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

// write the data to the request stream before you actually make the 
// the request.
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

// actually make the web request and get the response.
// this will hold the response from the request when it completes
var response = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```